# Outlook macros are not enabled unless I enable all macros, which, it tells me, is potentially dangerous

Tags: vba, outlook

I created a macro to work in Outlook (2016). Eventually got it working, but once I restarted Outlook, it didn't work any more.

Unless I select the option to 'enable all macros (not recommended)' - it says that the macros in the project are disabled. It doesn't come up with any option to enable them when I start the application.

I have changed security, signed it with SelfCert, closed Outlook - killed the process and restarted it. I have had the code on ThisOutlookSession, and on a separate module.

Frustratingly... it will only run if I enable all macros, which, it tells me, is potentially dangerous.

What can I do?

Running Office 2016 on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

When you're cresting own signature or with self-created signature, then save it only by setup with signature and later by closing - exit Outlook don't confirm to save it (it's configuration already saved on signature level).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same situation. I've created a macro which was working fine at beginning and after restart of the Outlook I got the same error message.

Please be aware that with this solution you might put your system on risk. I only opened documents which I knew that comes from trusted source or were written by me

The best solution would be to sign the macro.

**Go to: File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Macro Settings -> select Enable all macros**
[image]